# unable to install plugins on Jenkins instance in openshift

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, openshift

I have tried to follow [this](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1071-installed-jenkins-ci-server-how-do-i-lookup-and-install-plugins) tutorial and install the Nodejs plugin on my Jenkins instance.

Neither "Manage Plugins -> Advanced" page, click on "Check now" nor uploading the plugin file worked.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Jenkins log ?  This can be accessed from jenkins_url/log/all

Answer (score 2):

i found a solution for the problem by simply adding https:// to the upload sites url.

go to "Manage Plugins -> Advanced" page and change update site from http:// to https://

change: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
to:     https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an issue with jenkins being served over an https address, and the plugins being served over an http address, which your web browser will not allow.  If you use the developer tools console in your web browser, you will see this happen and get an error.  You will need to download the plugins and manually install them.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. And ">rhc tail jenkins" does not show any issue.
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Feb 12, 2014 7:52:52 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Workspace clean-up
Feb 12, 2014 7:52:52 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Workspace clean-up. 2 ms
Feb 12, 2014 3:15:58 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Fingerprint cleanup
Feb 12, 2014 3:15:58 PM hudson.model.FingerprintCleanupThread execute
INFO: Cleaned up 0 records
Feb 12, 2014 3:15:58 PM .AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Fingerprint cleanup. 1 ms